# Do .Net AppDomains provide protection against rogue C libraries?

Tags: c#, c, multithreading, appdomain

I have a C library that is *not* threadsafe -- and probably will never be.  I'm calling it from C# with PInvoke and that's working out quite nicely.

Now that C library has to be called from a C# program that certainly is multi-threaded.  I can manage this in the C# by having each instance of the C code called from separate AppDomains, except that doesn't seem to be working out very well.  I'm still getting a lot of cross-thread problems in the C library.

Will AppDomains isolate the C code mess (globals, etc..) from each other or no?  If not, what will?

Comment: Is it possible to load the library multiple times in C# as you can in C/C++ by copying the original and dynamically loading it again? Cheap, but effective way around it!

Comment: No. It seems that native code loaded in the same process -- no matter what the method -- shares memory space.  It would all have to be in another process completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, AppDomains will not help. If you call into your C lib concurrently, it doesn't matter which AppDomain the calls come from.

If the C lib is not thread-safe, you will have to serialize access to it. Actually, having multiple AppDomains makes this harder - you will have to synchronize across the domains.

Answer (score 1):

I think AppDomains are a construct which isolates only managed code.

You have to synchronize the access to your c lib with the c#/.NET synchronization primitives available (for example use `lock` blocks).

Answer (score 1):

If you have global/shared variables in the C library, and you need to isolate those, you have to spin up separate processes.